# How to set up a custom template in djangocms

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I've successfully installed **djangocms** on a Ubuntu machine, and now I would like to integrate a custom template bought from Envato.

After I have installed it, djangocms came with its own simple template files which are located in `mysite/templates`:

**base.html**

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{% block title %}This is my new project home page{% endblock title %}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        {% render_block "css" %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% cms_toolbar %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        {% show_menu 0 1 100 100 "menu.html" %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        {% render_block "js" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**feature.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        {% placeholder "feature" %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% placeholder "content" %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**menu.html**

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache %}

{% for child in children %}
    <li class="{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}
        {% if child.selected %} active{% endif %}
        {% if child.children %} dropdown{% endif %}">
        {% if child.children %}
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                {{ child.get_menu_title }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}"><span>{{ child.get_menu_title }}</span></a>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    {% placeholder "content" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I have read their documentation but I haven't found anything related to some custom template integration. Could anyone please lead me in the right direction ?

---

EDIT1:

I have added in CMS_TEMPLATES:

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('page.html', 'Page'),
    ('feature.html', 'Page with Feature'),
    ('index.html', 'oriel.io') # this is what I added
)
```

but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Add your templates to [`CMS_TEMPLATES`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/configuration.html#cms-templates) in your settings file.

Comment: I've done this (see my edit) and nothing happened. The first two pages were there from beginning. If I cut off the first two I get an error which says: `template_choices = [(x, _(y)) for x, y in get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')]
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: That error means you have a typo or something in that setting (one of it's values has more than two items in the tuple). Are you sure you correctly copy/pasted the setting and that there isn't a second definition of CMS_TEMPLATES further down in the settings file?

In a shell, can you print settings.CMS_TEMPLATES?

PS: Ideally CMS_TEMPLATES should be a list of tuples, not a tuple of tuples

Comment: When I am trying to run `python manage.py shell` it gives me the same error. I don't have any duplicates in `settings.py`

Comment: it worked with a list of tuples but my css and js files aren't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I recently met the same problem! So let me try to explain

**1)** You should extend PageAdmin in admin.py

In admin side, when you want to choose template for page ('advanced settings') it will call *AdvancedSettingsForm* by default. but we must to extend too to give your templates.

```
class ExtendedPageAdmin(PageAdmin):
    def get_form_class(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if 'advanced' in request.path_info:
            return ExtendedAdvancedSettingsForm
        elif 'permission' in request.path_info:
            return PagePermissionForm
        elif 'dates' in request.path_info:
            return PublicationDatesForm
        return self.form
```

and DO NOT forget unregister and register

```
admin.site.unregister(Page)
admin.site.register(Page, ExtendedPageAdmin)
```

**2)** OK) You have choosen ('advanced settings') and there must be choice among your custom templates.

```
class ExtendedAdvancedSettingsForm(AdvancedSettingsForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExtendedAdvancedSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    template_choices = [(x, _(y)) for x, y in get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')]
    self.fields['template'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=template_choices)
```

**3)** Ok, wee see custom templates for page, but there will be error if you want to save it. It's because of Page model. It looks like this:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Page(six.with_metaclass(PageMetaClass, MP_Node)):
    """
    A simple hierarchical page model
    """
    ...
    template_choices = [(x, _(y)) for x, y in get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')]
    ...
    template = models.CharField(_("template"), max_length=100, 
               choices=template_choices, default=TEMPLATE_DEFAULT
               help_text=_('The template used to render the content.'))
```

**4)** So you should change template_choice during **init** the Page object. Let's use signals

```
def after_page_init(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance._meta.get_field_by_name('template')[0]._choices = []

def patch_cms_page():
    from cms.models import Page
    from django.db.models.signals import post_init
    post_init.connect(after_page_init, sender=Page)
```

and finally call patch_cms_page() in urls.py )